Solution Verification (RMO Problem involving PHP)
The following problem is from the RMO (Regional Mathematical Olympiad) in India:

A computer program generated $175$ positive integers at random, none of which had a prime divisor greater than $10$. Prove that there are three numbers amongst them whose product is cube of an integer.

My solution was as follows:
Let the numbers be represented by $2^a3^b5^c7^d$. Now, if we have $5$ numbers, we can always find three numbers whose sum is a multiple of $3$, we need, by PHP, $5 + 4 + 4 = 13$ tuples $(x, y)$ to ensure that there exist $3$ tuples $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3$ and $y_1 + y_2 + y_3$ are both divisible by $3$. By similar logic, we need $13 + 12 + 12 = 37$ tuples to ensure a similar condition for tuples $(x, y, z)$ and $37 + 36 + 36 = 109$ tuples for tuples $(x, y, z, w)$. But if we have $3$ such tuples, and each of our aforementioned numbers can be associated with a tuple, then we have $3$ numbers whose powers are multiples of $3$ after multiplying.
I was quite unsure of my answer, simply because $109$ is a much stronger bound than $175$. Is the question asking for a weak bound, or is there a fault in my logic?

The setters may have been giving you an opportunity to use an easier argument: each index is equal to 0, 1 or 2 modulo 3, so there are $3^4=81$ possibilities for the pattern (mod 3) of the indices. If there are three copies of any of these in the list their product will be a cube, so we can have at most 162 integers without being able to guarantee a cube. The reason not to say 163, rather than 175, might have been to avoid giving a hint towards this argument. Your bound is tighter because you have ruled out also cases where three numbers have distinct indices  (mod 3).

That is... a lot simpler of an argument. But, my overcomplicating the problem notwithstanding, the logic I used is correct?

I don't understand where you got 13 from. I can only find at most 8 pairs without three of them summing to a multiple of three in both co-ordinates.

If we have 13 points, and we divide them based on $x \text{ mod } 3$, by PHP, we must have 5 points in one modulo group. By what we previously said, we can find 3 among these 5 such that the sum of their $y$ coordinates is divisible by 3, and since all of the $x$ coordinates are congruent to each other mod 3, the "sum" of the three tuples is divisible by 3.

I see. That's a good argument, but doesn't give the lowest bound because if you have 12 pairs and, in the first co-ordinate, no more than 4 in each modulo group you must have exactly 4 in each modulo group. Then you can only assign the second co-ordinates in each group by having two modulo groups appearing twice; now it will be possible to choose one pair from each modulo group in the first co-ordinate so that their second co-ordinates are all the same or also come one from each modulo group.

So even 109 is not the strongest possible bound; i. e, we could find a stronger bound for tuples of size 2 and apply the same logic, and so on.

As for the true minimum, the answer is 21, so the bound of 175 is very weak. Hence it's not surprising to me that there are lots of different solutions which use a much higher cutoff.
Consider the bijection between $ (a, b, c, d) \pmod{3}$ with cards in the game of Set, where we map the index respectively to numbers, colors, shapes, and textures of the cards.
It is a well-known fact (easily searchable, but not easy to prove. I'm sweeping a lot of work under this rug) that given any 21 cards, we can always find a set of 3 cards, where each attribute is either all the same or all different. This was proved by Pellegrino back in 1971 (G. Pellegrino. Sul massimo ordine delle calotte in S4,3. Matematiche (Catania),
25:149–157 (1971), 1970).
For cards in a set:

If the attribute is all the same, then the corresponding sum of the index is a multiple of 3.
If the attribute is all different, then the corresponding sum of the index is 6, which is a multiple of 3.

So given any 21 positive integers that satisfies the conditions, we translate them into cards in the game of Set, find the set that exists, and translate that back to give us 3 integers whose product is a perfect cube.
